# issues returning pyspark dataframe using for loop

Tags: for-loop, pyspark

I am applying for loop in pyspark. How can I get the actual values in dataframe . I am doing dataframe joins and filtering too.

I havent added dataset here, I need the approach or psuedo code just to figure out what I am doing worng here.

Help is really appreciated, I am stuck since long.

```
values1 = values.collect() 
temp1 = []
for index, row in enumerate(sorted(values1, key=lambda x:x.w_vote, reverse = False)):
    tmp = data_int.filter(data_int.w_vote >= row.w_vote)
    # Left join service types to results
    it1 = dt.join(master_info,dt.value == master_info.value, 'left').drop(dt.value)
    print(tmp)
    it1 = it1.withcolumn('iteration',F.lit('index')).otherwise(it1.iteration1)
    it1 = it1.collect()[index]
    # concatenate the results to the final hh list
    temp1.append(it1)
    print ('iterations left:', total_values - (index+1), "Threshold:", row.w_vote)
```

The problem I am facing is the output of temp1 comes as below

```
DataFrame[value_x: bigint, value_y: bigint, type_x: string, type_y: string, w_vote: double]
iterations left: 240 Threshold: 0.1
DataFrame[value_x: bigint, value_y: bigint, type_x: string, type_y: string, w_vote: double]
iterations left: 239 Threshold: 0.2
```

Why my actual values are not getting displayed in uutput as a list

Comment: Tilo, your recent activity shows very little effort in tackling the topics yourself. Consider trying to resolve the issues yourself before adding a couple of posts on SO every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` applied to a Dataframe execute the `__repr__` method of the dataframes, which is what you get. If you want to print the content of the dataframe, use either `show` to display the first 20 lines, or `collect` to get the full dataframe.